# C# - Seperate last name, first name in string that's seperated by comma

Tags: c#, string, csv

I have an **ASP.NET Core 3.1 Console Application** that is reading an **OFAC** csv file that is **"|"** delimitted.  The database table has a **FirstName** and **LastName** field that will hold the first and last name of these individuals. The problem is that the **OFAC** file has the full name in one string such as "last name, first name". I am able to read the file correctly, but I just want to be able to store the last name and first name in seperate properties so I can update them into our database as such.

**Note:** Alot of these names have **two words for their last names** and **two words for the first name**, and some do not.

**Another Note:** You can find **OFAC** file from **https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.pip** by clicking this [link](https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.pip) to get a better understanding of the file format I am parsing.

**Example names from OFAC file:**

"CRUZ, Juan M. de la"

"ESCOBAR BUITRAGO, Walter"

"GALINDO, Gilmer Antonio"

"GOMEZ BERRIO, Olmes de Jesus"

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

I want to seperate this string to have whatever is ***before*** the comma to be stored into the **LastName** field, and everything ***after*** the comma to be stored into **FirstName** field.

**What I have tried:**

I get this value **"CRUZ, Juan M. de la"** when reading the full name as such:

```
FullName = fields[1],
```

However, when I try to do a split on the comma for the name I get this result **System.String[]** as such:

```
LastName = fields[1].Split(',').ToString(),
```

Can anyone help me seperating any word(s) ***before*** the **','** and assign it to the **LastName** field, and every word(s) ***after*** the comma be assigned to my **FirstName** field ***regardless*** of how many names they have in their first or last name.

Comment: `Split()` return a `string[]` and when the method `ToString()` is called on an array, there is no overload, so it defaults to returning the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are splitting into an array, but then not indexing which element of the array to use for each field.

```
var nameParts = fields[1].Split(',');
var lastName = nameParts[0];
var firstName = nameParts.Length > 1 ? nameParts[1] : string.Empty;
```

Additionaly you may want to handle cases where there are more than one comma in the string and replacing with a space.

```
var firstName = nameParts.Length > 1 ? string.Join(" ", nameParts.Skip(1)) : string.Empty;
```

Comment: This did the trick. And thanks for the tips on handing cases where there are more than one comma!

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
  static string ReverseName(string name)
    {
        return string.Join(",", name.Split(",").Reverse()).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Nice little helper method! I'll be adding this to my collection!

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if I understood correctly, but it's quite trivial as

```
string fullname = "CRUZ, Juan M. de la" ; // == fields[1]
string lastname = fullname.Split(',')[0];
string firstname = fullname.Split(',')[1];
```

Comment: I tried this but got an index out of bounds error :(

Comment: that code isn't dealing with missing or more than 1 comma in the fullname, as you specified